# eclipselink JPA get only specific columns with list object in it

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a very complex value object with lots of sub objects with one to one, one to many relationship as below

```
@Entity(name = "objectA")
@Table(name = "A_table")
@Converter(name = "ynBooleanConverter", converterClass = BooleanYNConverter.class)
@NamedQuery(name="findPartOfA",query="select a.id.value,a.str,a.objBList from objectA a where a.id.value = :id")
public class A extends SuperEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ID id;

    @OneToOne ......
    private anotherObject1 objt1;

    @OneToOne ......
    private anotherObject2 objt2;

    @OneToOne ......
    private anotherObject3 objt3;

    @Column(name = "STR")
    private str;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "objectA", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<ObjectB> objBList;

    //Lots of other objects.......

     .....
}
```

Object B is a much simpler entity

```
@Entity(name = "objectB")
@Table(name = "B_table")
@Converter(name = "ynBooleanConverter", converterClass = BooleanYNConverter.class)
public class B extends SuperEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ID id;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "r_roid", referencedColumnName = "r_roid")
private A aObj;

@Column(name = "strCode")
private String strCode

@Column(name = "strValue")
private Boolean isOk

.....

}
```

I need to retrieve a result such a way that the resultset A will have only id, str and object B list. For this I have create a `@NamedQuery(name="findPartOfA",query="select a.id.value,a.str,a.objBList from objectA a where a.id.value = :id")` and trying to execute as below

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("findPartOfA");
query.setParameter("id", id);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// List<A> results = query.getResultList(); // Giving Same error
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
for (Object[] objects : results) {
    System.out.println(objects);
}
```

I am getting  "The state field path 'a.objList' cannot be resolved to a collection type.

What wrong in this query?? Do i need to explicitly use join with ObjectB??

Comment: clearly you cannot select a multi-valued field in JPQL, as per the JPA spec!

Comment: Why not just read in your A entities and benefit from caching?  Lazy relationships means those relationships are only fetched IF accessed, and you can join fetch your relationship to B in the query.  Otherwise, build the collection yourself by querying for the Bs that reference the specific A with the ID you are looking for.